# Laravel Passport Trying to get property 'secret' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-passport

I'm using laravel and trying to make an `Authenthication` with `Laravel passport`. So I've done it by looking on the docs and youtube but I got this error. this is my `AuthController` that I requested and the error.

AuthController.php

```php
public function register(Request $request) 
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required|max:55',
            'email'=>'email|required|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|confirmed',
            'who'=>'required'
        ]);

        $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        // Get access token
        $accessToken = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

        return response(['user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
    }
```

ErrorsException

```
{
    "message": "Trying to get property 'secret' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php",
    "line": 96,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php",
            "line": 96,
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php",
            "line": 71,
            "function": "createRequest",
            "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\HasApiTokens.php",
            "line": 67,
            "function": "make",
            "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\AuthController.php",
            "line": 26,
            "function": "createToken",
            "class": "App\\User",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "function": "register",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\AuthController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "call_user_func_array"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Panji\\xampp\\htdocs\\papa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 225,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
.
.
.
}
```

I've searched it on google but I can't found anything that mention `Trying to get property 'secret' of non-object`. I've tried `php artisan passport:install` so I got the `personal_access_clients`, but nothing's work.

**NB**

it's actually registered the user, but got this error response.

Comment: Did you find the solution??

Comment: yes, but i forgot. sorry bro

Comment: I solved it, ran this example https://github.com/leandrouti/laravel-passport-sample and compared it with my code, did some changes and it works. Is Laravel 5 but it is adaptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

THIS IS FOR LARAVEL 7 AND LARAVEL/PASSPORT 9.0

The first thing is to run the `php artisan passport:client --personal`.

Inside your database table ***oauth_clients***, under column ***name***, look for ***Laravel Personal Access Client***.

Copy the ***secret*** beside `Laravel Personal Access Client`.

Open `AuthServiceProvider`, then paste the secret inside the ***boot*** method where the `CLIENT_SECRET` is below:

```
Passport::personalAccessClientSecret(config('CLIENT_SECRET'));
```

And don't forget to also add the ID of the secret from your database.

```
Passport::personalAccessClientId(config('ID'));
```

Note: Use the quote along with the ID and CLIENT_SECRET as config() is expected to get a string.

Comment: IF you want to use only personal tokens, run => php artisan passport:client --personal

Answer (score 5):

Run this command: `php artisan passport:install --force` and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered a similar error while using Passport in the project. Fetching response while registration of user from mobile app - registration using OTP instead of password.

For me, the error arose due to doing a `php artisan migrate:fresh` as this was deleting all **oauth** data present in the DB.

So, just using `php artisan passport:client --personal` after running fresh-migrations, the error was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command: `php artisan passport:install --force`
The output will be something like:

> Encryption keys generated successfully.
> Personal access client created successfully. 
> Client ID: 24332432-2343-3423-8c52-2342333 
> Client secret: dfgdfgfdgfdgdfdfBvV3esUczLMkWsJ 
> Password grant client created successfully.
> Client ID: 92342333-4233-4343-9234-32423 
> Client secret: D3FD5fd5f5dmfmdDmffDmffmdDmfdmdn

Open the .env file and paste the client-id and the client secret from the password-access-client lines above like this:

PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID=24332432-2343-3423-8c52-2342333
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET=dfgdfgfdgfdgdfdfBvV3esUczLMkWsJ

Answer (score 1):

Removing these 2 lines from .env file works for me

```
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID="client-id-value"
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET="unhashed-client-secret-value"
```

Comment: In fact, that was it for me. I set up a unit-test scenario with a fresh db, called php artisan passport:install but since the old CLIENT-info was still in .env it did not work until I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

The only code in Passport that uses a property by that name is the model `Laravel\Passport\Client` that maps to `oauth_clients` DB table, so I suggest checking if that table is created and accessible for your app.

Comment: yes it wasn't empty, there are 2 Laravel_personal_access_client thing.

Comment: I took a look at my tables and found that in ```oauth_clients``` I have 1 row, but the ```user_id``` appears null

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to make an authenthication for users, the passport is overkill.
however, if you want passport, use password grant in this case.
you are using authorization_code grant type and the secret client key lost in your code
https://laravel-news.com/passport-grant-types

Comment: wait, I'll try it. so does that mean using password grant in laravel passport is a must?

Comment: It doesn't work. I think it doesn't have anything to do with `grant password` because I've seen it on youtube it works fine without `grant`

Answer (score 0):

i just added Passport Personal Access Client details in .env file

```
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID=94d36aec-fca4-46dd-b851-b4ca72a1cfe9
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET=C73SddSiirwKZzo3JxG0NcwNkASyOEynQq8bTQ3o
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error with Laravel ^10.15 / Passport ^11.8. I received an 'Attempt to read property "secret" on null' error when trying to generate a token. The user would be created, but the token generation would fail. After digging in, I found a mismatch of client id values in the DB between the `oauth_clients` and `oauth_personal_access_clients` tables. Once I ensured the `oauth_clients` record id column matched the `oauth_personal_access_clients` client_id value, the error resolved.

In my case, this defect occurred from manually updating keys and only updating the record in one table.